# OpenGL GLX application only runs when started from QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glx

We are developing a Qt application on Ubuntu that among other things uses GLX.

The application runs fine when started from QtCreator but when started from the terminal, it just exits saying

```
Could not initialize GLX
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've seemingly broken down everything to a difference in the environment settings but can't find out what exactly causes this.

It still starts fine when I reduce the QtCreator run environment to

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

Any ideas on what this difference could be or where to keep looking?

*The environment is an up-to-date Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, QtCreator 3.0.1, Qt 5.2.1*

*Graphics card is a GTX 1060 running with NVIDIA 375.66 drivers.*

**Update 1:**

I seem to be able to rule out that unsetting certain environment variables has the desired effect as `env -i bash -c 'DISPLAY=:0 myapp'` yields the same error.

Comment: In a terminal: `optirun myapp`.

Comment: @Ripi2 `libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast`

Comment: same for `primusrun myapp` but that it also segfaults afterwards.

Comment: Seems you need a Nvidia driver update.

Comment: I'm already on 375.66. And as I wrote, I works, when started from inside QtCreator.

Comment: Does `glxinfo` show something weird?

Comment: I didn't see anything weird: https://pastebin.com/8TDaTsNw